Configuring StatsD Receiver is creating issue using opentelemetry-collector-contrib peoject
I am configuring statsd to send custom metric from AWS EC2 instance on which splunk-otel-collector.service is running to Splunk Observability Cloud to monitor this custom metrics.
I have followed the steps mentioned in the https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/statsdreceiver to setup statsd as receiver.
receivers:
  statsd:
    endpoint: "localhost:8125" # default
    aggregation_interval: 60s  # default
    enable_metric_type: false   # default
    is_monotonic_counter: false # default
    timer_histogram_mapping:
      - statsd_type: "histogram"
        observer_type: "histogram"
        histogram:
          max_size: 50
      - statsd_type: "distribution"
        observer_type: "histogram"
        histogram: 
          max_size: 50    
      - statsd_type: "timing"
        observer_type: "summary"

I have a problem in setting service for this statsd as receiver, as per github doc below configuration is written for the exporters, but I am not sure how this will work.
exporters:
  file:
    path: ./test.json

service:
  pipelines:
    metrics:
     receivers: [statsd]
     exporters: [file]

I also tried setting exporters in service section "receivers: [hostmetrics, otlp, signalfx, statsd]" and "exporters: [signalfx]" in the agent_config.yaml file as mentioned below, when I restart the "systemctl restart splunk-otel-collector.service", splunk otel collector agent stop sending any metric to the  Splunk Observability Cloud and when I remove statsd (receivers: [hostmetrics, otlp, signalfx]) then splunk otel collector agent starts sending any metric to the  Splunk Observability Cloud.
# pwd
/etc/otel/collector

# ls
agent_config.yaml  config.d  fluentd  gateway_config.yaml  splunk-otel-collector.conf  splunk-otel-collector.conf.example  splunk-support-bundle.sh

service:
  extensions: [health_check, http_forwarder, zpages, smartagent]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [jaeger, otlp, zipkin]
      processors:
      - memory_limiter
      - batch
      - resourcedetection
      #- resource/add_environment
      exporters: [otlphttp, signalfx]
      # Use instead when sending to gateway
      #exporters: [otlp/gateway, signalfx]
    metrics:
      receivers: [hostmetrics, otlp, signalfx, statsd]
      processors: [memory_limiter, batch, resourcedetection]
      exporters: [signalfx]
      # Use instead when sending to gateway
      #exporters: [otlp/gateway]

What should be correct/supported exporter for the statsd as receiver?
Thanks
